# How to Add a line strikethrough or modify css in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add line strike though or change background colour of a list element when a corresponding tick button is clicked kindly suggest a way to do so ..
Is there any way similar to jquery's  ex - `$("p").css("background-color");`
& for beginners which will be more suitable to grasp who is coming from jq background  Class component or Functional

```js
  const [input, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  // passing  entered
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const lp = (event) => {
    // let c = [1,2,34,55]

    event.preventDefault();
    // if no input nothing will happen return none
    if (!input) return;
    // using spread operator its used whenever we need to add array data to exiting array
    const newTodos = [...todos, input];

    setTodos(newTodos);
    // clearing input text
    setValue("");
  };
  const handeldel=(index) => {
    // console.log(index)
  
    todos.splice(index, 1);
    setTodos([...todos]);  
   
    // const newTodos = todos.splice(index, 1);
    // setTodos([...newTodos]); 

  
  }

const markdone =() => {
  // how to mark complete
}

  return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-center font-weight-bolder alert-info mb-5">Tasks To Do <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list text-success"></i></h1>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 container">
          <input
            className="form-control border-primary font-weight-bold"
            style={{ height: 60 }}
            placeholder="Enter Text here"
            type="text"
            value={input}
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button
              className="input-group-append font-weight-bolder "
              style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
              onClick={lp}
            >
              {" "}
              <i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-2x p-2"></i>{" "}
            </button>
          </div>
       
        </div>
        {todos.map((x,index) => (
          <ol  style={{ listStyle:"outside" }} className="container">
            <li className="font-weight-bolder table-bordered text-capitalize alert-secondary " style={{fontSize:30}}>
              { x }<i class="fas fa-check-circle float-md-right text-success" onClick={markdone}></i>  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt  text-danger float-md-right" onClick={()=>handeldel(index)}></i>
            </li>
          </ol>
        ))}

        
        {/* for future ref */}
            {/* <div >
        {data.map((user) => (
          <div className="user">{user.id + "  " + user.name 
          }</div>
        ))}
      </div> */}
      </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the code for you here
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-chaplygin-ry5ed?file=/src/App.js

The main things i changed is that i added an Id  using uuid(npm i uuid) to each new li as well as a completed state.

Also I passed an event parameter to the markdone function

```
const markdone = (e) => {
    const element = todos.findIndex((el) => el.id === e.target.id);


    const newToDos = [...todos];
    console.log(element);
    
    newToDos[element] = {
      ...newToDos[element],
      completed: !newToDos[element].completed
    };
    setTodos(newToDos);
 
  };
```

So First i am trying to find the index of the element target element by compairing the ID's.

then I am cloning the array and using the spread operator I am returning the element but changing the completed state to the oposite. So if it is true, then it will become false and vice-versa.

On the `<li>` I am passing a conditional classname based on the state of "completed".
So if completed is true then it will get a class of "li-completed li" if it isnt true then it will get a class of 'li'.  You can target these classes on css ofcourse.

Please have a look at the link above you to get the full changes.

Comment: @Lp-Tester I updated the link so now you can see the whole code

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping me out got an even simpler method to achieve using just toggle functionality as below on the mark done function might be useful for beginner's

```js
 const [line, setline] = useState(false);

const markdone = (index) => {
    console.log(todos,index)
    setline(!line);
   
    // setll(true);
  };
```